# Creating a tunnel to host my dynamic ip website at home

Tags: apache-http-server, http, tunnel

I have a very powerfull machine at home and I would like to use it to create a website. The equivalent in money for this server would be 1000$/month.

Since my IP is dynamic in theory (event when it didnt change the last months) I cant use it directly

I want to get a virtual host machine and create a tunnel (in c or c# language) to connect this virtual machine with my home website. That machine will not have any other thing.

My question is if this is the right approach.

Comment: Are you asking what hardware you should use to host a website at home?

Comment: as you can see... no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are reinventing the wheel many times over. For the sake of this post I'm going to accept your claim about it being worth $1k per month in hosting and assume you have the bandwidth.

First off, you can do this without a tunnel/VPN by simply using Dynamic DNS - particularly if your IP changes very rarely.  That is the simplest approach.

If you want a tunnel, it would seem a lot less work to use an existing VPN system like OpenVPN.  This will create a robust tunnel but does have an overhead - in reality most systemscan  offload the encryption/decryption to custom routines on the CPU (Google AES-NI), so load is typically inconsequential.   There are plenty if VPN providers that sprcialise in offering a static IP over this service - likely cheaper then running a VPS.

Talking of this reminded me that I solved this problem for my niche ISP when Internet was in its infancy and we were beholden to the big telco for any kind if DSL offering. I offered tunnels using pppd - The optional encryption of pppd sucked, but its an off-the-shelf option if you want a raw tunnel.  You might also want to look at an IPIP tunnel as another unencrypted ready alternative.

If you write a programming you are going to reinvent the wheel and learn a lot if painful lessons, like why tunnels should be UDP even though websites are TCP, that you can't just write a single piece of code to do this, you will need to write a client and server, and method if checking its up etc. In fact, it sounds like you are trying to reinvent a proxy or load balancer - and one that you could almost (but not quite) recreate using just iptables rules - you could certainly do it with iptables DNAT rules and some light scripting to follow the IP to update.

In short, if you want to learn, have fun - but this is a solved problem.

Comment: Dyndns is not valid since it is for a future website with tons of users. Yes I have the bw. I have been checking OpenVpn today but i'm not sure about it... i dont need encryption ... site will be https only and i dont see dual encryption as an adventage here. I have programmed a socks server, a socks client and a proxy server the last week already... and I had this in mind when thinking in this.

Comment: If it exists i'm not interested reinventing the wheel, but actually I dont know how is it done, for example google, they have an ip for the searcher but it is +1000 machines really, i suppose that a router is tunneling the petitions to the different computers , i was looking for a similar stuff but with software since i cant have access to that balanced router.

Comment: Anyways  thanks for your response, it is well explained. I will check the IPIP to see if it is what i'm looking for... the other option, the iptables rules with dynamic script is a good option that i would like to check

Comment: about load balancer, i didnt know about them, they looks promising  https://geekflare.com/open-source-load-balancer